# Wget to download Wikipedia text

Tags: nlp, scrapy, wget, wikipedia

This is what I want to do:
Given an initial url (eg. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_scientists), I want to visit all the links on that page (relevant links of course).
Each link corresponds to another page containing several other links (eg. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_American_scientists). I want to visit each such link so that I can extract xml information from them.
Can this be done using wget? Someone suggested I should use Scrapy, however I am facing problem installing it.
The hierarchy to crawl looks like this: List of Scientists->List of American Scientists->Bryan Hayes (And a lot more scientists).

My target is to extract basic information from these wiki texts, like a person's name, organization, age, etc.

PS: I am a NOOB with good understanding.

Comment: Before you do anything like this, read http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page and related documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than scrape Wikipedia, you can [just download the whole thing in one go.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download)

There are tools for [scanning categories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:CatScan), so you don't have to crawl the articles yourself.

Of course, you could just skip Wikipedia altogether, as [there's already an effort to do this](http://dbpedia.org/About).

If you're still intent on extracting information from Wikipedia itself, start by exploiting Wikipedia's own structure and formatting. Writing a tool to pull information from [InfoBoxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Infobox) would be a good start. If you absolutely want to get information out of the text, the first place to begin is with a [named entity recognizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition). This finds all of the named entities in text. If you're too lazy to deploy an existing one, you're working on English, and you don't mind a few extra errors, you can just grab sequences of tokens that start with capital letters.

From there, you're probably looking for particular patterns in the data to get information from. You can use a parser, such as the [Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml), to exploit grammatical relations of the language in text. There are also systems that work on finding patterns in strings without any traditional or explicit grammatical knowledge, like [Etzioni et al's KnowItAll](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0004370205000366) system. Depending on what exactly you're looking for, one may be better than the other.